# setup xen on two phisical interfaces

Tags: interface, xen

does anybody know how to setup XEN to use 2 interfaces? I have a subnet of local IPs on eth0 and subnet of external IPs on eth1. I want containers to be as on a dom0: eth0 and eth1 routed respectivly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. I'll discribe it in case of someone need it

So far I had eth0 interface and br0 configured.

On dom0 I add additinal bridge. I call it br1

```
addbr addbr br1
```

Then I bind it to physical interface eth1

```
addif br1 eth1
```

Next, I am on Debaian, I configure /etc/network as follows

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 172.16.15.240
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 172.16.15.0
        gateway 172.16.15.1
        broadcast 172.16.15.255
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp on
        bridge_maxwait 0
        bridge_fd 0

auto br1
iface br1 inet static
        address 91.135.xxx.xxx
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        network 91.135.xxx.xxx
        broadcast 91.135.xxx.xxx
        gateway 91.135.xxx.xxx
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp on
        bridge_maxwait 0
        bridge_fd 0
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Then in config file for container add virtual interface as follows

```
vif         = [ 'ip=172.16.15.243 ,mac=00:16:3E:18:AF:C3,bridge=br0',
                'ip=91.135.xxx.xxx ,mac=00:16:3E:DD:2D:00,bridge=br1'
             ]
```

That's it. After reboot both dom0 and domN, you will have container connected to phisical interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using two NIC interfaces with Xenserver 6.2. I created them using XenCenter, I'm doing exactly what you're asking, using eth0 on all VMS for local connections and eth1 for internet.

How to do it.

If you have the pool created you need to go to the Networking tab, there you can add a network using the "Add Network" button and then follow the wizard.

If you have any more questions, there is a guide from Citrix. http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/34969-102-704897/reference.pdf

Good luck.